# Why I can't reference the implement of function defined in .h file?

Tags: c, header-files

**IDE:** VS code

**gcc version:** 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

I new in C , now I have three files:

**Get_para.h**

```c
#ifndef _GETPARA_H_
#define _GETPARA_H_
extern double C;
extern double dEarthAngularVelocity;
...
extern void calParameter();
#endif
```

and **Get_para.c**, which is the implement of Get_para.h

```c
#include <math.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define pi M_PI

double C = 3e8;
double dEarthAngularVelocity = 7.29210e-5;
...

void calParameter(){
...
}
```

then, I want to include Get_para.h in **test.c** and call calParameter function which is implemented in **Get_para.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Get_para.h"

int main(){
   calParameter();
   printf("%lf\n",dSemiMajorAxis);
}
```

I use 'run code' in VS,the command in terminal is:

```bash
if ($?) { gcc test.c -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
```

the output is:

```bash
C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuWLUIl.o:test.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `calParameter'
C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuWLUIl.o:test.c:(.rdata$.refptr.dSemiMajorAxis[.refptr.dSemiMajorAxis]+0x0): undefined reference to `dSemiMajorAxis'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but I want to just include the "Get_para.h" then I can use the implement of them in "Get_para.c".I search this in google , others' code didn't work on my computer. Now I guess the problem is the parameters of gcc, but can't figure out what is it or what knowledge of C I need to know to solve this problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell `Get_para.c` is neither compiled nor linked.

Comment: Why are you tagging both `C` and `C++`? Those are two very different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile the implementation of the function too:

```
gcc Get_para.c test.c -o test
```

Consider learning a build system, like cmake.

> ```
> #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
> ```

For a macro like this to work, it has to be defined *before* any includes.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
```

> ```
> #define _GETPARA_H_
> ```

It's not valid to define your macros with leading `_` followed by an upper case letter. Such identifiers are reserved. For example, use:

```
#define GETPARA_H_
```